# Потеря качества картинки на сайте

Tags: png

В редакторе pixlr сделана картинка формата png с шахматным фоном вместо белого цвета. Я считаю, что при размещении ее на сайте с фоновым рисунком фоновый рисунок останется нетронутым там, где на вставляемой картинке прозрачный фон. Но этого не произошло. Почему? [Труды Чайного Клуба](https://teannuals.club)

Comment: уберите у класса `.site` белый фон `background-color: #fff;`

Comment: но я подозреваю, что это тоже не совсем то что Вам нужно, скорее всего белую рамочку Вы хотите сохранить

Comment: Не понял, о какой белой рамочке вы пишете. И на сайте установлен фоновый рисунок - "тетрадь в клетку". Я хочу, чтобы клетка осталась на белом фоне рисунка и в хидере

Comment: я в ответе показал рамочку посмотрите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно убрать фон `background-color: #fff;` у класса `.site` но это уберет всю заливку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и я подозреваю, что это не совсем то что Вам нужно, скорее всего белую рамочку Вы хотите сохранить.

Поэтому предлагаю в `css` правилах Вам прописать такое правило, если дело касается только этой картинки

```
img[src="https://teannuals.club/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/ainwonderland.png"]{
  background-image: url("https://teannuals.club/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/bg.jpg");
}
```

Таким образом Вы добавите вместо прозрачности клетчатый фон, будет эффект прозрачности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нет, это будет касаться всех иллюстраций на сайте

Comment: тогда в селекторе можете просто оставить `img` или создать какой-то специальный класс для таких изображений, это уже на Ваш выбор

Comment: это единственное решение которое возможно, потому что картинка с прозрачным фоном не очищает фон который находится под ней, она его просто не затирает

Comment: Да, благодарю. Так и хотел.

Comment: @e-lub Рад что помог. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)